# Lead created by a webtolead does not honour default value of checkbox

Tags: leads, web2lead

I have an checkbox defined on leads object which is set to true by default. When i insert a record through UI or dataloader, the field is set as true.
But interestingly, when the lead is generated by an WebtoLead form the checkbox is false. Is this a normal behaviour ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the Web2Lead isn't explicitly setting it false?

Comment: yes, i am sure. There is nothing in my form which accepts boolean value

Comment: Can you 'cheat' the web2lead and add that field as a hidden field set to checked?

Comment: This is going to be a part of managed package and i would not have any control on the webtoleads as such. The only way i can think of is to have a trigger to update the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old but I just also encountered this issue. The only way around it is to explicitly set a hidden input value on the HTML to be the desired value. In my case I was passing in a "Do not create Opportunity" boolean that would be passed to an invokable Apex class that converts the lead automatically, and since I needed it to be set to true by default, we have to include this in all of our forms:

```
<input type=hidden name="Do_not_create_Opportunity__c" value="true">
```

Hope you were able to solve it for your managed package scenario!